# Why does casting this double to an int give me 0?

Tags: c, casting

Sorry this has been confusing me for hours and nothing comes up on google about this. I'm programming in C, trying to convert decimal to binary, and I'm confused as to why this keeps giving me the right amount as input but the integer value is always 0.

even if I properly cast input as an int, it doesn't work (ie: int integer = (int) input;

```
main() {
double input;
scanf("%d", &input);
printf("input: %d \n", input);  // this will print fine
int integer = input;            // stores nums before decimal
printf("integer:%i\n", integer);   // this always prints 0
```

Comment: You actually do *not* have the correct value as a double.  What you have is an `int` value that has been stuffed into a `double` variable, because you used the wrong `scanf` format.  You then tried to print it, again using the wrong format, so it was interpreted as an `int` and happened to show what you expected.  But as a `double`, the value was quite different from what you expected (all of this is undefined behavior).  Hint:  FIX YOUR COMPILER WARNINGS.  Until your code compiles warning-free, you should not be posting questions about why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the wrong specifier to read -> `scanf()` or print -> `printf()` the `double`, do this

```
if (scanf("%lf", &input) == 1)
{
    printf("input: %f\n", input);
    printf("integer: %d\n", (int) input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need To Correct Format Specifiers.

```
main(){
    double input;
    scanf("%lf",&input);
    printf("input: %lf \n", input);
    int integer = input;  
    printf("integer:%i\n", integer); }
```

[Some Format Specifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP0rR.png)

Or you can read from [here](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c.html)